# Suggest a good Free & Open Source HTML5+JS gaming framework/engine?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML5+js game development or I can I am new to this html5 canvas experiments. But now I want to develop a game(simple racing game) using it.

So please suggest a good tutorial and framework/engine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Easel JS](http://easeljs.com/) - nice library.  [Tankster](http://www.tankster.net) was created using this.

[Melon JS](http://www.melonjs.org) - as Joel said.

[GameQuery](http://gamequery.onaluf.org/) - a jQuery library.

[Lime JS](http://www.limejs.com/) - another nice library.

[Jaws JS](http://jawsjs.com/)

Comment: Processing.js is also good http://processingjs.org/

Answer (score 6):

MelonJS: http://www.melonjs.org/

Comment: It uses a third party tiled map editor — cool!

Answer (score 4):

IIO Engine can be a good choice to develop an HTML5 game. Check out the iio engine [website](http://iioengine.com/). Also please, check out sample game from [this post](http://www.yusufaytas.com/implementing-html5-bomberman/).

Answer (score 3):

The Angry Birds game was created using ForPlay [ Now PlayN ] http://code.google.com/p/forplay/ . Its writing code in java cross compiled to js .

Comment: they also used box2d you can see in the credits of the game

Answer (score 3):

If you want to build a racing game you should really check out this tutorial, you'll write your own engine and learn all about how to go about a game like this:

http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2012/6/23/javascript_racer_v1_straight/

good luck !!

Answer (score 2):

LibCanvas: http://libcanvas.github.com/

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Enchant.js](http://enchantjs.com/). It is very easy to learn and nice to play with.

Start with these resources

- [How to Make A Simple HTML5 Game With Enchant.js](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23370/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-game-with-enchant-js)
- [HTML5 Game Programming with enchant.js](http://www.apress.com/9781430247432)
- [code.9leap.net](http://code.9leap.net/)