# source code for games that are web based

Tags: jcreator

I am looking into making a game using source code from a web based game. I am looking to make a game based upon moto rush 2 and other games with the same dynamics. The game can be found at addictinggames or a quick Google search should reveal it. Is there any standard way to go about this? Are there any rules I must follow when using source code?

Comment: Try, oh, I don't know, reading the license in the code and respecting it. If there's no license, it's safest not to reuse it. (Also, [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.")

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a legal advice web site. The only ones who can tell you about the legalities of using the source code are the holders of the copyright to that code or an attorney licensed to practice in your jurisdiction who is familiar with copyright laws. Voting to close as off topic. If you have questions in the future that fit the guidelines for this site as outlined in the [faq] and [about] pages, please ask it and we'll try and help get you an answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

That is a shockwave flash game http://games.playhub.com/swf/moto-rush-2.swf - so the source is not easily available.  You could do something like this; [How do you decompile a swf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97018/how-do-you-decompile-a-swf-file) but it is questionable, and the kind of thing you would not want to release to the public.

There are open source games, and you might be better starting with those.  Look here for lots of suggestions: [Suggest a good Free & Open Source HTML5+JS gaming framework/engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078875/suggest-a-good-free-open-source-html5js-gaming-framework-engine)